# Get my friend list from facebook - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my friend list in facebook with the following code:

```
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friendlists"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
                          }];
```

but the result is:

> ```
> data =     (
>             {
>         id = 200157003455826;
>         "list_type" = acquaintances;
>         name = Acquaintances;
>     },
>             {
>         id = 115504338587760;
>         "list_type" = family;
>         name = Family;
>     },
>             {
>         id = 115504328587761;
>         "list_type" = "close_friends";
>         name = "Close Friends";
>     }
> );
> ```

How can I get the list of all my facebook friends?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with this code:

```
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
                          }];
```

instead the other

Comment: This function returns only the friends who is currently using the app.